# stock analysis using SVM

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
date = []
price = []
with open(output_path_new) as datasource:
    r = csv.reader(datasource)
    next(r)
    for row in r:
        date.append(int(row[0].split('-')[2]))
        price.append(float(row[1]))
```

Trying to do the stock market analysis using python. When I run this I get the error

> date.append(int(row[0].split('-')[2]))
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Assign `row[0]` to a variable. Assign the result of `split` to a variable. Print them out and see whether they really do have enough values in them to be able to index them.

Comment: Can you create a full example with the smallest csv that still produces the error? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Add `print(row)` before the line which breaks. Then analyse why that line breaks with that value in `row`.